# Quasar dynamically checkboxes are not empty onload

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

When I try to have multiple checkboxes none of them are empty onload. Please see codepen:
https://codepen.io/cbrown___/pen/ZEWvGXq?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2Fvue-components%2Fbutton

Pretty simple I just want all of them to be empty onload of page.
How can I fix this?

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-sm">
      <span  v-for="(c,index) in categories">
      <q-checkbox v-model="val[index]" :label="c.label"></q-checkbox>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="q-px-sm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      val: [],
categories:[{id:1,label:'crime'},{id:2,label:'fun'},{id:3,label:'other'}]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying everything I came over a page where this was solved.

This is the right way of doing it:

`<q-checkbox v-model="val" :label="c.label"></q-checkbox>`